# GetObject not unloading from VBA Project Window

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA code

```
Sub test2()

Set xlobj = GetObject("C:\Users\osknows\Desktop\One of each\Jan_2011.xls")
With xlobj
    For Each wsobj In .Worksheets
     Set rngobj = wsobj.UsedRange
     arrArray = rngobj.Value
    Next
End With

Erase arrArray
Set rngobj = Nothing
Set xlobj = Nothing

End Sub
```

The problem is that once this runs and exits the sub the Jan_2011.xls details are still in the VBA project window. I would expect this to disappear by setting xlobj = Nothing

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line containing GetObject does two things: it opens the workbook and makes xlobj a reference to the workbook. When xlobj is set to nothing, the reference is cleared, but the workbook is still open. This can be avoided by adding the line

```
xlobj.Close
```

before emptying the variables.